# What are the benefits of writing Swift with REPL in Terminal?

Tags: xcode, swift, terminal, read-eval-print-loop

I've read some articles online that say, as a beginner, learning to code in the command line is better to get aquatinted with programming and writing code.  I want to learn Swift and have been following the chapter 'A Swift Tour' in Apple's 'The Swift Programming Language' iBook but have been doing so in Playgrounds (as suggested in the chapter).  Is there any benefit of me starting to write Swift in the Terminal instead of Xcode Playgrounds or is it purely a personal preference thing?

Answer (score 1):

A little research reveals e.g. [REPL vs Playground](http://thriftyswift.com/?p=10), where you can read, that in REPL, you cannot use `let`. Also, IMO, playgrounds can rather fast grow into some more mature prototypical implementation, while REPL is rather for seeing what some statement does.

Comment: You can use `let` in Swift REPL nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

In the command line environment, `Cocoa` and `UIKit` are not available. So you cannot do visual prototyping of your UI. Further, Playgrounds has lots of fancy features like letting you explore the history of a variable's value, and graphing numeric values over time. The downside is that as your Playground grows, it pre-emptively re-renders **all** the calculations, loops, and UI prototypes you've created after every statement you add. This makes it very slow, and prone to crashing. Or, it will fail silently on a syntax error somewhere in the file.

On the other hand, a command line REPL is only concerned with evaluating the current expression, so it's very fast and gives you instant feedback on errors. It's for focusing on the language proper, like syntax, basic data types, for loops, function syntax, and closures.

Comment: At that rate you're probably overthinking it. You don't *have* to use all of that playground stuff, and its advanced features are little to do with App development and more just a faster way to explore & learn with instant feedback. If I had to split the difference I would stay within Xcode and learn its ups and downs since all your serious App development will happen within an Xcode project. If Swift was a serious server-side environment and that's where you were headed, the story would be different.

Comment: Swift 2.0 / Xcode 7 beta is stable enough to begin right away.